# Error no 1 Operation not permitted: error in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

when I try to read file from Spyder using pandas I am getting error:

```
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/arunramji/Downloads/Sourcefiles
```

I granted full disk access too , still not working, any idea how to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("/Users/arunramji/Downloads/Sourcefiles/_Price/train.csv",
                  engine="python")
```

Comment: Could it be that the file is opened somewhere else?

Comment: Nope @oliverm . Also same is working fine from Jupyter notebook!!

Comment: Is the working directory I spyder the correct one. /Users seems strange to me for a Linux file system root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 1\] Operation not permitted after macOS Catalina Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update)

Comment: opening Spyder from terminal seems to be solving this issue .     

but not sure why its occurring when Spyder opened thru anaconda window!!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the macOS Catalina update.

You should update your Anaconda Navigator package by running this from the terminal.

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Remember to do this for correct environment and restart Navigator.

For more info, see this link [https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11387](http://Problem%20with%20permissions%20in%20macOS%20Catalina)