# Permission error in Anaconda in MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, security, permissions, anaconda, privacy

Using Anaconda (or, to be more precise, the Spyder environment) on MacOS Catalina (MacOS 10.15.3), I get the error "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" during operations on files stored in my computer.

I informed on the web, and I tried everything. I tried to uninstall Anaconda from my computer and to re-install it, in particular the 2019.10 distribution, which should work (see https://www.anaconda.com/anaconda-distribution-2019-10/). But I continue to get this error.

Then I made a search here, and I tried some suggestions which I read from other questions, such as updating the security and privacy preferences for Anaconda (see [PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted after macOS Catalina Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update)). These didn't work as well.

I don't know what else to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise what you are trying to do? Are you trying to run a script, update a module or something else? Can you post an example command and a complete error output?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script. In that script I call an Excel sheet file, from which I read some data which I convert in Python lists. When I try to run it, I get the error: "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/filepath/filename.xlsx'", meaning that Python seems to not have the "permission" to read that file.

Comment: Canyou post the script excerpt?

Comment: It is just something like ```from xlrd import open_workbook; book = open_workbook('/filepath/filename.xlsx')```. By the way the same script runs on other OS, so I'm sure that the problem is not in the script but in the permission that Python on Catalina has to read the local files.

Comment: Could you check that the file actually exists and has proper permissions? What does `ls -l` run in the directory give you?

Comment: Everything is OK with the file, it is only an issue with the permissions of Python in Catalina, as it has been extensively reported on the web (see the links I posted in the question). Still, it is not working.

Comment: I have the same issue I can open and view in Finder on Mac OS X Monterey but cannot ls from the t.  There must be some lower level permissions in shell.