# How to resolve Permission denied on Mac when using Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, file-permissions, visual-studio-mac

I have a very basic problem in a Console app which i am developing on Mac (VS2019 Community Edition). Given a folder under Downloads path, I am unable to display the filenames.

Below is my code

```
using System.IO;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source = "/Users/username/Downloads/samples";

            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(source))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Path does not exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading the files..\n\n\n");

                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(file);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: \n\n {ex.Message}\n\nInner Exception: \n\n {ex.InnerException} " +
                    $"\n\nStack Trace: \n\n {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

So the exception I am getting is this:

```
Access to the path '/Users/username/Downloads/samples' is denied.

Inner Exception: 

 System.IO.IOException: Operation not permitted
```

I am guessing it is something to do with folder permissions or running VS as admin rights which I am unaware of. Has anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: You should spend some time studying the basics of macOS/Linux, such as the `sudo` command.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, but I am not sure how can a running console app could execute sudo command in C#

Comment: Open terminal run: man chmod. Change rbac of folder, something like: chmod -R 755 /path/to/directory

Comment: Contrary to the above commenters, this is likely because of macOS's Full Disk Permissions model. The solutions are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update .