# PermissionError: [Errno 1] for os.rename as quick action

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, automator

This question represents the latest issue encountered when solving another problem. Let me explain the current issue first and leave the initial difficult at the end.

```
os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

This *Python* command works when running the Python script in Automator (using the the run button on the top right).

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/user/Library/Scripts/move.py"
```

However, when run as a quick action, it throws the error

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Library/Scripts/move.py", line 6, in <module>
os.rename(folder_path, folder_nath)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
```

All suggested solution tell me to grant various programmes full disk access. However, after having done so for Terminal, Finder, Automator and *bash*, I still see the error. I even changed the permissions for the folder to be renamed in the 'Get info' box. Nothing has helped.

---

This problems seems to be isomorphic with a problem I had earlier with another commend not working as a quick action:

```python
os.system("""/bin/mv \"""" + old_path + """\" \"""" + new_path + """\"""")
```

This command works in *PyCharm*; it works when I run the *python* code containing it in Automator (using the Run button in the top right).

```sh
/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/user/Library/Scripts/move.py"
```

However, it does *not* work when I run this workflow as a quick action triggered by a keyboard short-cut: the quick action clearly works as the little cog rotates, but the file remains unchanged.

Comment: I'm unsure why you have so many unnecessary quotes - `os.system("/bin/mv '" + old_path + "' '" + new_path + "'")` works fine, though it really should be `subprocess.run(["/bin/mv", old_path, new_path])` following best practices.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `os.rename( old_path, new_path )` performs the same function, and is much quicker and easier to type.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what happens and what do you want instead?

Comment: @TimRoberts Of course I forget the simple solution to the problem :facepalm:

Comment: I have so many quotes because sometimes the file-names contain quotation marks, so I just escaped it as much as possible to avoid errors.

Comment: Ugh, the code with shell commands will still fail if the path contains single quotes. Probably need to use shlex to fix that, or just use subprocess.

Comment: Are you running into a disk permissions issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update The disk permissions can vary per application.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that already. I have given this permission to Terminal, Bash, Finder, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. When it comes to quick actions like this, you need to grant full disk-access permission to the application open when you use the quick action.

As I use this quick action when using, for example, TextEdit, I needed to give TextEdit full disk-access permission.