# Python - OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file RSTP

Tags: python, macos, opencv, avfoundation, rtsp

I'm testing a small python script to capture images from an IP camera, via RTSP. I can open the video normally via VLC, and via CLI using ffmpeg, but using OpenCV with Python3, I get the error: `OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "rtsp://admin:admin123456@192.168.15.2:8554/profile0 "`

Also, I can open a local .mp4 video with the python script. It seems to be a problem when using RTSP with opencv.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import os

os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = 'rtsp_transport;udp' # Use tcp instead of udp if stream is unstable

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin123456@192.168.15.2:8554/profile0")

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open RTSP stream')
    exit(-1)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('RTSP stream', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Keep running until you press `q`
        cap.release()
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Trying to run the python script I get the error: `OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file rtsp://admin:admin123456@192.168.15.2:8554/profile0"`

Comment: try passing CAP_FFMPEG explicitly for `apiPreference`. on macos, you are getting AVFoundation (error string implies AVFoundation). -- check `print(cv.getBuildInformation())` for the video I/O section.

Comment: Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    AVFoundation:                YES

Also tried passing CAP_FFMPEG explicitly, same error.

Comment: you can't use ffmpeg, OpenCV wasn't built with ffmpeg. find a build with ffmpeg. you need ffmpeg for this. AVFoundation can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on MacOS 12.5.

I have `FFMPEG: YES` on my `cv2.getBuildInformation()` but still get the error `OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file`.

However, using the same conda environment (same `opencv-python` version) but via a jupyter notebook instead of a script gives no error and the file is read without problems!

**SOLVED:**

My problem was with VS Code not having permissions to access the disk. This solved my problem, except I needed to give permissions to VSCode instead of Terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250494/20581881

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzntO.png)