# Pycharm on macOS: Operation not permitted on listdir() under Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, macos-monterey

I'm trying to do an os.listdir() on a server exported directory.

When I run the Python3 program from the shell, it works fine.  But when I run it under the Pycharm debugger, I get a PermissionError exception.

The directory is set to "Read and Write" for "everyone".  I've also restarted the Pycharm application.

I'm running on macOS Monterey (old hardware).

Any hints?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - That worked!  Could you make your comment into an answer?  I'll approve it and you will get points!

Comment: I'm posting as Community Wiki (and thus disclaiming the points) because I'm 99.99%+ sure this is duplicative (but too lazy right now to actually _find_ the duplicate and close accordingly).

Comment: ...the most obvious candidate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update, but that's for Terminal not having the relevant permissions, as opposed to an editor. (OTOH, there are certainly _answers_ that discussion permissions for one's IDE, and it's arguably the same problem with the same fix, just for two different apps being the ones from which the permissions need to be inherited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS has additional per-process access control restrictions beyond filesystem permissions -- this is basically what's at play when it asks you if process X should be able to access your Documents/desktop/etc.

Go to "Privacy and Security", then "Files and Folders"; find pycharm therein, and make sure "Network Volumes" is enabled.