# Can't Install Certificates in MacOS

Tags: python, certificate, mime

I am writing a simple service with python that sends a email using MIME.
and it run the code and gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 360, in send
    self.sock.sendall(s)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiansahafi/PycharmProjects/test/Email/main_email.py", line 10, in <module>
    DatabaseRepositoryInstance.update_database_task()
  File "/Users/kiansahafi/PycharmProjects/test/Email/DatabaseRepository.py", line 22, in update_database_task
    sendEmailInstance.send_email(subject, body, to_email)
  File "/Users/kiansahafi/PycharmProjects/test/Email/send_email.py", line 63, in send_email
    server.quit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 999, in quit
    res = self.docmd("quit")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 426, in docmd
    self.putcmd(cmd, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 373, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 363, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('Server not connected')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Server not connected
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

after searching i found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) that says that i have to install the certificates in python from /Applications/Python 3.11/Install Certificates.command and when i try to open it (even with the sudo command!) it gives me this error:

```
❯ /Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2023.11.17)
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 40, in main
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'cert.pem'

Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

i searched about this as well and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update) that says i should give the terminal (and Finder!) full disk access which I did and the problem is not solved.

[Picture that shows the permissions of Finder and Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LKTZ.png)

thanks in advance for any solutions.

my macOS version is 14.0, and my machine is a m1 macbook pro and my code editor is pycharm.

i have tried upgrading python and pip but not sure if that would do anything...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the command you used?

Comment: i added new pictures of the errors and the commands

Comment: Please add all commands as text and not as images.

Comment: Done. and thanks in advance for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was from interpreter which was 3.9 after changing it to 3.11 the problem was solved!